# How to create a Dynamic table in GWTP

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwtp, gwt-platform, gwt-places

I am a new GWTP user and I am not sure how to create a table in GWTP. I know how to make one in GWT.

```
// Create a CellTable.
CellTable<Contact> table = new CellTable<Contact>();
// Create name column.
TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
  @Override
  public String getValue(Contact contact) {
    return contact.name;
  }
};
```

But This doesn't seem to work in GWTP. Can someone please help me with getting the values on a button press  in a GWTP program.

Comment: I've not used it, but I think there's an ActionCell and ButtonCell class you might be able to use. Try googling one of those and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm aware you asked this question over a week ago but you may still be stuck on it so here goes. You just have to make sure you put the right bits of logic in the `Presenter` and `View` respectively.

It's no different from MVP (Model-View-Presenter) without GWTP in principle:

Your `Presenter` has the job of getting the data to fill the `CellTable`, and passing it to the `View`:

```
public class TablePresenter extends Presenter<TablePresenter.MyView, TablePresenter.MyProxy>
{
    public interface MyView extends View
    {
        void addData(List<Contact> accounts); // pass data to view
    }

    // proxy and constructor omitted for brevity...

    @Override
    protected void onReveal()
    {
        super.onReveal();

        // server action to get contacts
        dispatchAsync.execute(new GetContacts(), new AsyncCallback<GetContactsResult>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(GetContactsResult result)
            {                   
                getView().addData(result.getContacts());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Your `View` has the job of initially setting up the `CellTable` and its `Column`s, as well as receiving the data from the `Presenter`. Here I show a `TextColumn` and a `Column` using a `ButtonCell`:

```
public class TableView extends View implements TablePresenter.MyView
{
    @UiField
    CellTable<Contact> table;

    // use a dataprovider to hold the data
    private ListDataProvider<Contact> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Contact>();

    // COLUMNS
    TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn;
    Column<Contact, String> buttonColumn;

    @Inject
    public AccountsView(Binder uiBinder)
    {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

        initTable();
    }

    private void initTable()
    {
        nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>()
        {
            @Override
            public String getValue(Contact object)
            {
                return object.name;
            }
        };
        // now add the column to the table
        table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");

        buttonColumn = new Column<Contact, String>(new ButtonCell())
        {
            // the text of the button
            @Override
            public String getValue(Contact object)
            {
                return "Delete " + object.name;
            }
        };

        // set the button action
        deleteColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Contact, String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void update(int index, Contact object, String value)
            {
                // whatever you want to do when you click the button
                Window.alert("You pressed " + object.name);
            }
        });
        fileTable.addColumn(deleteColumn);

        // link dataprovider to the table
        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void addData(List<Contact> contacts)
    {
        // clear the dataProvider's list
        dataProvider.getList().clear();

        // pass the data into the list
        dataProvider.setList(contacts);

    }

}
```

Then in your UiBinder:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <b:CellTable ui:field="table" />
</g:HTMLPanel>
```